# double integration via u-subtitution

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm having trouble with this double integral, maybe someone can help me out: $\int_1^2 \int_0^{lnx} 4x \ dy dx$

My attempt: $$\int_0^{lnx} 4x \ dy = 4xy \big |_{y= 0}^{y= lnx} = 4x \ln(x) $$
$$ \int_1^2 4x \ ln(x) \ dx = 4\int_1^2 x \ ln(x) \ dx  $$
$u = ln(x), du = \frac{1}{x}, v = x, dv = 1$
$$4 \ [ x \ ln(x) - \int_1^2 x \frac{1}{x} dx] = 4 \ [x ln(x) - \int_1^2dx] = 4\ [x \ ln(x) - x \big |_1^2]= $$
$$= 4[ 2\ ln(2) - 2)- (0-1)] = 8 \ ln (2) - 4$$

The textbook answer is $8 \ln (2) - 3$.

Comment: In your integration by parts you have $\int u(x)v(x)dx$ on the left.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_1^2x\ln(x)\,{\rm d}x$$

$$u=\ln(x)\quad \underbrace{v=x^2/2}_{dv = x\,dx}$$

$$\int_1^2u\,{\rm d}v = [uv]_1^2 - \int_1^2v\,{\rm d}u$$

$$\int_1^2v\,{\rm d}u = \int_1^2\frac{x}{2}\,{\rm d}x$$

I leave the rest to you.

Comment: you mean it's $ 4 (\frac{x^2}{2} ln(x) \big |_1^2 - \int_1^2 \frac{x^2}{2} du) = 4[\frac{x^2}{2} ln(x) \big |_1^2 - (\frac{1}{2}) \frac{x^3}{3} \big |_1^2)$, I'm still getting a different answer: $$8 ln(2) -  \frac{14}{3} $$

Comment: @Bob check your second integral. I wrote $\int_1^2 x/2\,{\rm d}x$ not $x^2/2$

Comment: Why is it $\int_1^2 \frac{x}{2}$, I thought it should be integral of $v$, and $v = \frac{x^2}{2}$?

Answer (score 0):

But remember what du is ,you multiply the "v" term by the derivativative of the logarithmic function ("du - term")

$$\int_1^2v\,{\rm d}u = \int_1^2\frac{x^2}{2}\,{\rm d}\ln(x)$$